# exercise about metric spaces: prove that the function is a metric

Tags: metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ a metric space, $\alpha >0$ (fixed ) and $T: X \rightarrow X$ a map such that exist $n \in N$,   where :

$$ d(T^n x , T^n y) \leq  \alpha^n d(x,y), \forall x,y \in X$$

Define $h(x,y) = [d^2 (x,y) +  \frac{1}{\alpha^2} d(Tx,ty)+...+ \frac{1}{\alpha^{2(n-1)}} d(T^{n-1}x,T^{n-1}y)]^{1/2}$. I want to prove that $h $ is a metric on $X$. My problem is the triangle inequality ... I am getting anywhere .. Someone could give me a help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: When you say  'for a fixed $n\in N$...' is that we only know there is some $n$, or it works for all $n$? I just want to be clear on the quantifier.

Comment: "there is some n" is the right interpretation. thanks for note this. thanks for your commentary . I edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I suppose that your $h(x,y)$ is
$$h(x,y)=[d^2 (x,y) +  \frac{1}{\alpha^2} d^2(Tx,Ty)+...+ \frac{1}{\alpha^{2(n-1)}} d^2(T^{n-1}x,T^{n-1}y)]^{1/2}$$
Please edit if this is true.
Now put
$$u(x,y)=(d (x,y),  \frac{1}{\alpha} d(Tx,Ty),\cdots, \frac{1}{\alpha^{n-1}} d(T^{n-1}x,T^{n-1}y))\in \mathbb{R}^n$$, and $u(x,y)=(u_k(x,y), 0\leq k\leq n-1)$.
Let $N$ be the Euclidian norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then you have $h(x,y)=N(u(x,y))$.

Let now be $x,y,z$ fixed. For each $k$ we have
$$u_k(x,y)\leq u_k(x,z)+u_k(z,y)$$
Hence 
$$h(x,y)\leq N(u(x,z)+u(z,y))\leq N(u(x,z))+N(u(z,y)=h(x,z)+h(z,y)$$
and we are done